# Adding plot of y=x/log(x) to a graph using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the curve x/log(x) onto the following graph:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,x,"r")
plt.title("Happy Numbers v y=x v y=x/log(x)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Happy Numbers")
plt.xlabel("Number Tested")
plt.plot(x,y,'.')
plt.show()
```

I have tried adding the following line of code but this causes an error:

```
plt.plot(x,x/(m.log(x))
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what was the error? what are `x` and `y`? what is `m`? please post a  [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If `m` is `math`, then it won't work obviously.

Comment: Sorry I am new to python can you explain why it will not work because of m?

Answer (score 5):

It only makes sense to use positive values for `x` else the log is undefined, and to ensure `x` is not equal to one, else we will encounter a division by zero scenario.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(1.1, 10, 100)
y = x/np.log(x)
plt.clf()
# plt.figure(1) # I am not sure we need this?
plt.plot(x,x,"r")
plt.title("Happy Numbers v y=x v y=x/log(x)")
plt.ylabel("Number of Happy Numbers")
plt.xlabel("Number Tested")
plt.plot(x,y,'.')
# plt.show() # See previous comment.
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: MWE]

**Why your code might be failing?**
It is unclear what `m` is (the `math` module?). It may be division by zero error. I suspect it might be the container for `x`, as standard list by list division may not give the expected results. I would recommend using the `numpy.array` container, as most operations would be element wise, which is likely what you are looking for.

**A nicer plot:**

The following I think looks nicer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(1.1, 10, 100)
y = x / np.log(x)
plt.clf()  # Ensures a clean plotting canvas.
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(8, 6))
plt.rc('font', family='serif', serif=['Computer Modern Roman'], size=16)
plt.plot(x, x, "k-", label='$x$')
plt.title("Happy Numbers $v$")
plt.ylabel("Number of Happy Numbers")
plt.xlabel("Number Tested")
plt.plot(x, y, 'k--', label='$x/\\log(x)$')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', frameon=False, handlelength=3)
plt.savefig('example.pdf', format="pdf")
```

[image: nicer plot]